# Laravel Eloquent Relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a table of Questions and another table that has Answers.  A question has many answers, and an answer belongs to a question.  These relationships have been defined in the Question and Answer model and work as expected.

However, when I try to get a bunch of questions with the answers, Eloquent returns an empty array.

```
return Question::with('answers')
                ->where('category_id', $input['category'])
                ->take($input['num_questions'])
                ->orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))
                ->get();
```

I get the following response...

```
{
"id": "1",
"category_id": "1",
"question": "Why did the chicken cross the road?",
"feedback": "Why did you ask that?",
"created_at": "2014-04-24 16:57:48",
"updated_at": "2014-04-24 16:57:48",
"answers": []
},
{
"id": "2",
"category_id": "1",
"question": "How awesome is Laravel?",
"feedback": "That's debatable.",
"created_at": "2014-04-24 16:57:48",
"updated_at": "2014-04-24 16:57:48",
"answers": []
}
```

When printing the raw queries I see the following...

```
{
"query": "select * from `questions` where `category_id` = ? order by RAND() asc",
"bindings": [
    "1"
],
"time": 2.11
},
{
"query": "select `id`, `choice`, `correct` from `answers` where `answers`.`question_id` in (?, ?, ?, ?)",
"bindings": [
    "3",
    "4",
    "1",
    "2"
],
"time": 0.92
}
```

When I run these queries manually, I see answers, but for some reason laravel shows an empty array.  Why?  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove the ->select() code off your model, then do:

```
return Question::with(array('answers'=>function($query)
            {
                $query->select(array('id', 'choice','question_id')); // question_id is mandatory because Laravel need it for mapping
            }))
            ->where('category_id', $input['category'])
            ->take($input['num_questions'])
            ->orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

I was manually selecting what fields I wanted returned in the model.  This apparently breaks when you select multiple rows rather than a single row.

```
    return $this->hasMany('Answers')->select(array('id', 'choice'));
```

Removing that ->select() code off the model fixed it.

Comment: The problem was that you didn't select parent id `category_id` so despite the results were there, Eloquent couldn't match them to the categories.